# Insets applied TopAppBar turns transparent?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to build a screen with the content starting right behind the TopAppBar, using [`accompanist-insets`](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/). However, the app bar is always transparent.

How to make it a solid/non-transparent navigation bar?

**Current Output**

[image: ezgif com-gif-maker]

**Code**

```kotlin
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
var isScrollStateChanged by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
isScrollStateChanged = scrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset != 0

val position by animateFloatAsState(if (isScrollStateChanged) 0f else -45f)
val listItems = (1..100).toList()

ProvideWindowInsets {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .systemBarsPadding(),
        color = Color.White
    ) {
        Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            TopAppBar(
                content = { Text("Hello nav bar!") },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset(0.dp, position.dp)
                    .alpha(min(1f, 1 + (position / 45f)))
                    .navigationBarsPadding(bottom = false),
                backgroundColor = Color.Red
            )
            LazyColumn(
                state = scrollState
            ) {
                items(items = listItems) {
                    Text(
                        "Hello $it",
                        Modifier
                            .padding(20.dp)
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doesn't have transparent background. Actually it's `LazyColumn` has transparent background, and `TopAppBar` is placed underneath.

Using `Box` you put items on top of each other, so second one will be under the first one. Reorder them:

```
Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    LazyColumn(
        state = scrollState
    ) {
        items(items = listItems) {
            Text(
                "Hello $it",
                Modifier
                    .padding(20.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
    }
    TopAppBar(
        content = { Text("Hello nav bar!") },
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset(0.dp, position.dp)
            .alpha(min(1f, 1 + (position / 45f)))
            .navigationBarsPadding(bottom = false),
        backgroundColor = Color.Red
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: I feel so stupid now. lol. Thanks Philip.